# Rails 6 - issue creating a callback to validate specific text is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So I am trying to create a callback to perform a quick validation before save.

What I currently am trying to do is validate that a url parameter being passed to a form hidden field is not changed and matches exactly one of three options:

owner_operator, broker_shipper or carrier

currently I have tried this, however, it still allows the form to be saved even if the parameter dosnt match one of the options...

my callback as it sits now.

```
accounts.rb

before_validation :validate_account_type

  def validate_account_type
    return if account_type == 'owner_operator' || 'broker_shipper' || 'carrier'
  end
```

any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `account_type` against each account type literal.

```rb
account_type == 'owner_operator' || 'broker_shipper' || 'carrier'
```

above expression evaluates like below

```rb
(account_type == 'owner_operator') || 'broker_shipper' || 'carrier'
```

Even if `account_type == 'owner_operator'` evaluates to `false` then next condition in the expression is `broker_shipper` evaluates to `true`. So your record is always valid as per the condition.

In ruby, except `nil` and `false` everything is `true`.

So solution is

```rb
account_type == 'owner_operator' || account_type == 'broker_shipper' || account_type == 'carrier'
```

even better

```rb
ACCOUNT_TYPES = %w(owner_operator broker_shipper carrier)
def validate_account_type
  ACCOUNT_TYPES.include? account_type
end
```

Learn about operator precedence will help you in long run.

Comment: Fantastic! this worked like a charm!!! thank toy so very much!